# Implement history in C shell

Tags: c, shell, history

I am creating a simple C shell and have been asked to implement a History feature, does anyone know how I would do this? It should be able to print the history, save it and load it.

Comment: See http://whathaveyoutried.com and the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Your shell has to process every command that it reads. Part of the processing would be to record each command to an internal data structure. Add shell commands to write that data structure to disk and load the data structure from a file, and you're done.

Comment: make a queue type struct and add to the end of the queue with each action?

Answer (score 2):

you can use array of `char *` to save your commands in the memory.

```
char *history_command[MAX_COMMAND];
```

and use file in disk to save the `history_command` array.

each time the `history_command` array is changed than remove the file and save the `history_command` in the same file name

Keep a `start` index (initially zero) along with size, so if `size < MAX_COMMAND`, you write to `history[size++]`, and if `size == MAX_COMMAND` you write to `history[start++]` (followed by `start %= MAX_COMMAND;`). This way your array becomes circular (**@shahbaz** suggestion)

Otherwise you can use linked list for such behvior. It's a FIFO queue. so treated with linked list could be another solution

Comment: _and move each element in the array to the previous element indice_, this is quite inefficient. One better way would be to keep a `start` index (initially zero) along with `size`, so if `size < MAX_COMMAND`, you write to `history[size++]`, and if `size == MAX_COMMAND` you write to `history[start++]` (followed by `start %= MAX_COMMAND;`). This way your array becomes circular.

Comment: @shahbaz yes good idea. I missed it. I will update my answer with that

Comment: @shahbaz there is something you missed. if I want to print the history . I will not get the history in the order with the solution you gave

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL: You will if you traverse the array in the right order.

Comment: @KeithThompson yes indeed. we have to start print history from the `start` index and not from 0. (I miss it)

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL: Deleting my comment; I'll delete this one later.